# Angular quill-editor does not align text left

Tags: angular, alignment, quill, text-alignment

Here, I am trying to align my text in a range 0-34 (i.e. one line) to left

**Code snippet:**

```
quill.formatText(0, 34, {
      'color': "White",
      'align': 'left',
      'background-color': "Black"
}, 'api');
```

**Expected:**

After adding above code - the text from index 0 to length 34 should be aligned left inside the editor.

**Actual Result:**

The text remains in center.

I need help to align range of text in different alignment(left/right/center)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [their documentation](https://quilljs.com/docs/api/#formattext):

> For line level formats, such as text alignment, target the newline character or use the [formatLine](https://quilljs.com/docs/api/#formatline) helper:

```
quill.formatText(0, 34, {
  'color': "White",
  'background-color': "Black"
}, 'api');

quill.formatLine(0, 1, 'align', 'left');
```

Comment: this doesn't appear to work in ngx quill version ^19.0.1. Right and center both work. Left does not.